# Python, Pandas: shrinking a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

inside my application i have a dataframe that looks similiar to this:

**Example:**

```
id    |    address          |    code_a    |    code_b    |    code_c      |    more columns
1     |    parkdrive 1      |    012ah8    |    012ah8a   |    1345wqdwqe  |    ....
2     |    parkdrive 1      |    012ah8    |    012ah8a   |    dwqd4646    |    ....
3     |    parkdrive 2      |    852fhz    |    852fhza   |    fewf6465    |    ....
4     |    parkdrive 3      |    456se1    |    456se1a   |    856fewf13   |    ....
5     |    parkdrive 3      |    456se1    |    456se1a   |    gth8596s    |    ....
6     |    parkdrive 3      |    456se1    |    456se1a   |    a48qsgg     |    ....
7     |    parkdrive 4      |    tg8596    |    tg8596a   |    134568a     |    ....
```

As you may see, every *address* can contain multiple entrys inside my dataframe, the *code_a* and *code_b* are following a certain pattern and only *code_c* is unqiue.

What I'm trying to obtain is a dataframe where the column *code_c* is ignored, dropped or whatever and the whole dataframe is reduced to only one entry for each *address*...something like this:

```
id    |    address          |    code_a    |    code_b    |    more columns
1     |    parkdrive 1      |    012ah8    |    012ah8a   |    ...
3     |    parkdrive 2      |    852fhz    |    852fhza   |    ...
4     |    parkdrive 3      |    456se1    |    456se1a   |    ...
7     |    parkdrive 4      |    tg8596    |    tg8596a   |    ...
```

I tried the *groupby*-function, but this doesn't seemed to work - or is this even the right function?

Thanks for your help and good day to all of you!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do? Remove column C?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('address').drop(columns=['code_c'])`?

Comment: Try `drop_duplicates` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html then drop the column `code_c`

Comment: In this way you will lose information. E.g., for the first 2 rows, which one of the two elements in code_c to keep? Are you OK will losing this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `drop_duplicates` to do this

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[‘address’], inplace=True)
```

This will keep only a single entry per address

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
# in this way you are looking for all the duplicates rows in all columns except for 'code_c'  
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.difference(['code_c']))
```

```
# in this way you are looking for all the duplicates rows ONLY based on column 'address'  
df.drop_duplicates(subset='address')
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice in your example data, if you drop columnC then all the entries with address "parkdrive 1" for example, are just duplicates.

you should drop the column c:

`df.drop('code_c',axis=1,inplace=True)`

Then you can drop the duplicates:

`df_clean = df.drop_duplicates()`